# Filter, group and report on Users like Contacts

Tags: reporting, user-management, topics

My Salesforce app makes extensive use of native Reports on Sales Cloud data. In the future, we want to group the data by different User types. We want to introduce some grouping, filtering and segmenting on native Salesforce users, and my goal is to just use native features for that e.g.:

1. [Topic Tags](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.collab_admin_topics.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5) for Segmentation
2. List Views and Topic filters for filtering
3. Grouping by Topics in Reports

But I am unable to get multiple implementation ideas to work:

1. Relate User to Contact using ContactId field (cannot be written, seems to be internal for Portals only)
2. Relate Contact to User using Custom Lookup (doesn't help when filtering data by Record Owner)
3. Relate User to Individual object (Individual doesn't allow Topics)
4. Use Custom Permissions instead of Topics ([Are not visible in Reports](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdpCPUAZ/filter-on-group-membercustom-permissionpermission-set-in-lookup-filter-on-user))

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you go from a goal of _group the data by different User types_  to using Topics as a solution?

Comment: Weird, I know! But here is the story: Users get tagged with arbitrary properties and the reports on their record gets grouped by such Tags. E.g.: Opportunities amounts are grouped by Users with attributes "wine lover, fromBristol, haveReeceivedFormalTraining"

Comment: You're after customer segmentation - group users based on features/traits, then report on related records based on the segment. Standard reporting approach: many-to-many relationship between a segment and target object (e.g. Opportunity). Segment would be a custom object.

Comment: A Sales agent creating an Opportunity is NOT a customer but a user. My reports are interested in his or her traits and features.

Comment: Okay, user segmentation, same domain model in our comment applies. Some of our Sales/Service Cloud customers use Campaigns as a simple segment implementation.

Comment: How about a real answer? Not sure what you mean with Campaign segmentation.